# Finding the limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

I got the n'th term but clueless about what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$t_r = \dfrac{r(r+1)(2r+1)/6}{r^2(r+1)^2/4} = \dfrac23 \dfrac{2r+1}{r(r+1)} = \dfrac23 \left(\dfrac1r + \dfrac1{r+1}\right)$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
S_n & = \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^r t_r = \sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^r \dfrac23 \left(\dfrac1r + \dfrac1{r+1}\right) = \dfrac23 \left(\sum_{r=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^r}r + \sum_{r=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^r}{r+1} \right)\\
& = \dfrac23 \left(-\dfrac11 + \sum_{r=2}^n \dfrac{(-1)^r}r + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^r}{r+1} + \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+1} \right)\\
& = \dfrac23 \left(-1 + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{r+1}}{r+1} + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^r}{r+1} + \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\right)\\
& = -\dfrac23 \left(1+ \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
Now conclude the limit of $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$t_r=\frac23\cdot\frac{2r+1}{r(r+1)}=\frac23\cdot\frac{r+(r+1)}{r(r+1)}$$

$$=\frac23\left(\frac1r+\frac1{r+1}\right)$$

Set a few values of $r$ to find the [Telescoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) nature

and for integer $m>0,$ $$\frac32S_m=-1+\frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}$$

Comment: -1. Incorrect answer gets up-voted $3$ times.

Comment: @Adhvaitha, Please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: You just changed your answer. It was initially $1$ instead of $-1$.

Comment: @Adhvaitha, It is the approach, not calculation nor spoon feeding , which is the essence of MSE as I've realized

Comment: @Adhvaitha Rushing to downvote, even if the answer is incorrect, seems to be a little harsh. Why not write a comment to the answerer letting him/her know the mistake so that he will probably fix his answer?

Comment: @Timbuc, You took words from my mouth to pinpoint the prevailing practice here in MSE. Thanks.